# Create slugs programmatically

Tags: permalinks, draft

I'm updating programmatically posts in a WP 3.01 install, using custom made tools.
Sometimes I do change programmatically `post_status` from DRAFT to PUBLISHED using custom `SELECT` queries, however this seems spoiling posts permalinks.

When in a DRAFT state, posts have the following link structure

```
http://myblog.com/?p=73006
```

Could there be some "trick" to force a change in the link structure, generating the proper permalink?

Comment: Forgot to mention: once changed status from DRAFT to PUBLISHED, the permalink gets empty!

Comment: Errata: Sorry for the mismatching, I mean the slug gets empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to programmatically set the slug as you do so. An SQL trigger could do the trick. Don't forget to mind duplicate slugs as you write it.

Else, instead of publishing using the database, write a php script that calls the WP API.

Comment: calling `wp_update_post` should do it: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post

Comment: You mean I could use wp_update_post to update the post status? (BTW I have updatetd the title of the discussion, coz the problem lies into slugs)

Comment: Yeah, that would be the above-mentioned "using a php script" option. It's the recommend one, too, since you'll then get pinging, cache flushing where needed, etc.

Comment: Using wp_update_post is extremely slow... how is that?

Comment: Maybe it depends on revisions being created....

Comment: @Riccardo - `wp_update_post` ends up running the logic to set the slug. You *definitely* want to use it instead of direct SQL for this because direct SQL is not good practice when it can be avoid but also because `wp_update_post` does so much for you.

Comment: I've found a way to disable temporarily revision creation and seems faster now

Answer (score 2):

Create a `.php` file in root of your WordPress directory and write:

```
<?php
require( 'wp-load.php' );

$urunler = array(
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'post_type'      => 'urun',
    'post_status'    => null,
    'numberposts'    => -1,
);

$tumurunler = get_posts($urunler);
if ($tumurunler) {
  foreach ($tumurunler as $urun) {
    $urun->post_name = '';
    wp_update_post( $urun );   // Update the post into the database
  }
}
```

So this code loads all posts of `post_type=='urun'` and sets the `$urun->post_name` field to empty (this field defines the post permalink slug) then WordPress automatically fills a value for you when you call `wp_update_post()`. If you want to change `post_type'` to `'post'` or `post_type'` to `'page'` just change this line:

```
'post_type'      => 'urun',
```